# typescript complains about call signature when testing $componentController

Tags: angularjs, typescript, webpack, jasmine, tdd

I am trying to test an angular 1.5 component, but Typescript is throwing red in the console.

> (17,27): error TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'IComponentOptions' has no compatible call signatures.
>   PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 8 0.0.0) Component: RecipeContainer should have a defined component FAILED

Am I including the files incorrectly? (I'm using webpack to compile).

Am I missing a type definition?

Any help would be appreciated, been scratching my head for hours now.

---

**spec file:**

```
import * as angular from 'angular';
import 'angular-mocks';

import { RecipeContainer } from './recipe-container.component';
import { recipes } from '../recipe-store';

describe('Component: RecipeContainer', () => {
    let $componentController: ng.IComponentOptions;

    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('app'));
    beforeEach(angular.mock.inject((_$componentController_: ng.IComponentOptions) => {
        $componentController = _$componentController_;
    }));

    it('should have a defined component', () => {
        const bindings = { recipes };
        const component = $componentController('RecipeContainer', null, bindings); //webstorm underlines this line 
        expect(component).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

**component.ts:**

```
class RecipeContainerController implements ng.IComponentController {
    constructor(private $log: ng.ILogService) {
    }
    $onInit() {
        this.$log.info('inside onInit');
    }
}

export const RecipeContainer: ng.IComponentOptions = {
    bindings: {
        recipes: '<'
    },

    controller: RecipeContainerController,

    template: '<div>hello</div>'
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$componentController` has [`IComponentControllerService` type](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/angular-mocks/index.d.ts#L103-L111). Not `IComponentOptions`. If you use wrong type on the variable, you can expect that TypeScript type system will complain.

It likely should be

```
beforeEach(angular.mock.inject((_$componentController_: ng.IComponentControllerService) => {
  ...
```